# INA122p replace to INA126p

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier

I made a working circuit for an INA122p, for arduino, so it has a 5V PS . I bought 2 ina 126p ic's, because  they are      nearly the same, but when I change the ics, the 126p has a fixed 0,6v signal output. the gain is set to 500.

here is the modified circuit:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The INA126 does not have the same capabilities as the INA122. The 122 can work with input signals that swing as low as the most negative rail of the device which, in your example, appears to be 0V. The 126 has problems in this respect: -

[image]

I've circled the bit that shows the common mode input range when on a 5V/0V supply. Two things to note - the input range only goes down to about +1V and the output can only swing as low as about 0.6 volts. Here's the 122 equivalent picture: -

[image]

The input range includes 0 volts and the output looks like it will swing down to below 100 mV.

Comment: thank you for your answer, im really beginner in electronics, what should i change in the circuit? or is there any way to make this circuit work with the ina126?

Comment: Add a negative supply to the -Ve power pin - you only need about -2V to make it work down to 0V.

Comment: it's for a load cell, the signal isn't changing if i make pressure on the load cell. which is the -Ve pin? the LC's virtual ground or the negative signal coming from the LC?

Comment: Pin 4 is the -Ve power pin.

Comment: okay, now its 0.1v but still not changing on pressure.

Comment: No schematic = no more help!!! Put one in your question as an edit to show what you have now implemented following my advice.

Comment: i uploaded the photo, i hope it's good.

Comment: That's not a schematic - I need a circuit diagram with the latest modifications to produce -2V on the pin I talked about and I can't understand how your load cells are connected either. Also, what are those circles to the right?

Comment: i have a very limited knowledge, when you say -2v, i put 2 electrolyt capacitor, which halves the voltage on the 2 sides, and their common is "gnd". how should i make negative voltage from arduinos 5v?

Comment: No that won't work at all. To make the 126 work you need a negative supply on pin 4 relative to pin 5 (0V).

Comment: how can i make a negative voltage from arduino?

Comment: I don't know how you can do that given your current skill set. You could buy an isolating dc/dc converter that runs from the 5V but generates an isolated 3V3 that you can wire up to the circuit but it's probably cheaper to just get the correct device. you could do a proof of concept with the addition of a 1.5V battery inserted in the neg line (correct polarity). I think I've answered your question so if you still need more help then I suggest you raise a new question asking for options.